# Trying to Make a Sell Area for a ROBLOX Game

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a sell area for my lobby for a ROBLOX game.

Yet, whenever I step on the sell area (with points), I don't seem to get any cash and my points don't change.

Please help?

Here is my code:

```
local sellPart = script.Parent

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    sellPart.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
        local hrp = hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")
        if hrp then
            local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hrp.Parent)
        
            local zombpoints = player.leaderstats.Zombpoints
            local zombcash = player.leaderstats.Zombcash
        
            zombcash = zombpoints
            zombpoints = 0
        end
    end)
end)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are storing the NumberValue objects into variables, and then overwriting those variables. You are not modifying the data stored *in* the variables.

So when you use [NumberValues](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/NumberValue), you need to explicitly set their Value property.

```
-- get the point values out of the leaderstats
local zombpoints = player.leaderstats.Zombpoints
local zombcash = player.leaderstats.Zombcash

-- convert the points to cash and add it to cash pile
zombcash.Value = zomcash.Value + zombpoints.Value

-- reset the point counter
zombpoints.Value = 0
```